# Появление круга из центра

Tags: jquery, css3, javascript, css

Каким образом можно реализовать, что бы круг, например 50x50px начинал плавно появляться из своего центра.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/d4LVA/1/ примерно так (это ответ из другого вопроса, там чуть по-другому задача стояла)?

Comment: Пример хороший, но никак не могу понять как реализовать мою задачу.
http://jsfiddle.net/d4LVA/3/ вот что мне удалось сделать, но теперь нужно реализовать с эффектом bounce когда он заканчивает появление

Comment: через transitions эффекта bounce не добиться. тут надо использовать [animation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp) и [@keyframes](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp) соответственно. что касается вашего кода с background'ом, то надо бобавить background-size:cover например.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/7b7Dv/
Использовал обыкновенную анимацию CSS3, также в комментариях JS написал комментарий для IE6-9 и других браузеров, не поддерживающих `animation keyframes`. Надеюсь, это то, что вы добиваетесь.

Также, в анимации CSS можно попробовать использовать `transform` для того, чтобы изменить размеры.